# Updating Ruby version on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I'm trying to deploy a Rails (4.2.6) application on a Windows 7 system (customer requirement).

I installed rubystack-2.2.5-3 and this comes with Ruby 2.2.0, but my app was developed using Ruby 2.3.1. I started thin server as explained in the deploy instructions and then tried to run my app, but got an error "Method does not exist" and as it is running perfectly in my Linux box, I assumed that it is because of the Ruby version.

I can't install RVM or RBENV on Windows, right? So I researched Google and saw there was a Ruby 2.3.0 installer. I downloaded it and installed it. Then I updated the PATH variable to point to my new Ruby installation. But when I do a **bundle install** it still complains that my Ruby version in Gemfile (2.3.0) is different from my installed Ruby.

How can I tell it to run the new Ruby?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you're prepared to go with Cygwin you can [use RVM](http://blog.developwithpassion.com/2012/03/30/installing-rvm-with-cygwin-on-windows/).

Comment: I'm curious about Cygwin, @tadman. I seldom use Windows and never used it. Easy to install?

Comment: It's not as slick as what's coming in [Windows 10 Ubuntu integration](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/) but it's usually not to much trouble to get going. Ruby expects a fairly POSIX environment or it ends up being very difficult to use.